# How to get components of UStaticMesh Array?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

Hej,

In the below code, I'm trying to get the components of UStaticMesh Array, but i'm getting an error as follows.

> Error 1 error C2338: 'T' template parameter to GetComponents must be
>   derived from ActorComponent

In .h file

```
UPROPERTY()
        TArray<UStaticMeshComponent*> StaticMeshComponent;
UPROPERTY()
        TArray<UStaticMesh*> StaticMesh;
```

In .CPP file

```
StaticMeshComponent = TArray<UStaticMeshComponent*>();
StaticMeshtemp = TArray<UStaticMesh*>();

for (int32 i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    GetComponents<UStaticMeshComponent>(StaticMeshComponent);
    StaticMeshComponent[i] = CreateDefaultSubobject<UStaticMeshComponent>(temp);

    GetComponents<UStaticMesh>(StaticMesh);
    StaticMesh[i] = Cast<UStaticMesh>(StaticLoadObject(UStaticMesh::StaticClass(), NULL, *SMPath));
```

Is there any another function or method to get the components of UStaticMesh Array ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is not necesarry:

```
StaticMeshComponent = TArray<UStaticMeshComponent*>();
StaticMeshtemp = TArray<UStaticMesh*>();
```

Both arrays are initialized before running constructor.

**Problem:**

This code is OK:

```
 GetComponents<UStaticMeshComponent>(StaticMeshComponent);
 StaticMeshComponent[i] = CreateDefaultSubobject<UStaticMeshComponent>(temp);
```

StaticMeshComponent is derived from ActorComponent [UE Doc](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/API/Runtime/Engine/Components/UStaticMeshComponent/index.html).

And this is wrong:

```
 GetComponents<UStaticMesh>(StaticMesh);
```

Because as you can find in [UE Doc StaticMesh](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/API/Runtime/Engine/Engine/UStaticMesh/index.html), StaticMesh is not derived from ActorComponent.

**Solution:**

All you need is call [SetStaticMesh](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/API/Runtime/Engine/Components/UStaticMeshComponent/SetStaticMesh/index.html) function on each StaticMeshComponent that you created via CreateDefaultSubobject<...>.

Comment: Thanks for your clear explanation. I got new logic to solve this problem.